# Is it considered bad form to ask a rhetorical question?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

I've seen some people asking a question that they clearly already know the answer to, in order to share some information that might help others deal with a headache or otherwise avoid running into the same technical problem. In this sense its kind of more like a blog post than a regular question.

Sometimes these people wait for answers or even pretend they worked away for a while then solved it themselves, but sometimes they are even the first to add an answer on their own questions. I suppose it would not be a big deal but clearly it is "fishing for points", upclicks and reputation. Obviously doing this as two different usernames is immoral and against the terms of use, however, its less clear about those who do it from the same username.

In the interest of sharing useful information and knowledge, is this allowed, encouraged, or frowned-upon?

Comment: Why would anyone answer a rhetorical question?

Comment: @random Maybe they don't know its rhetorical. :P

Comment: Can I answer a question with another question? Should I?